# Does this statement calls constructor obj=new checker[10]?

Tags: java

```
 class checker

{

    public checker()

    {
        System.out.println("In the constructor");
    }
}
public class StringTesting {
    static String string1;
    static String string2;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        checker[] obj;
        obj=new checker[10];

    }
}
```

What can i do to call the constructor of all the 10 objects of class checker?obj=new checker[10] statement doesn't call the constructor i want to know why?

Answer (score 5):

Your current code doesn't create any objects of type `checker` - it just creates an array which is capable of holding references to objects of type `checker`. Initially every element in the array has a value of `null`. It's important to understand that the array element values aren't `checker` objects - they're just references. Multiple elements could hold references to the same object, for example, just like multiple variables of type `checker` could have values referring to the same object. (You can think of an array as a collection of variables.)

If you want to call the constructor, you need to do so explicitly. For example:

```
// Names fixed to be more conventional
Checker[] checkers = new Checker[10];
for (int i = 0; i < checkers.length; i++) {
    checkers[i] = new Checker();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`obj=new checker[10];` means you are creating an array that can hold 10 instances of `checker`. This does NOT create 10 instances of checker. So the `checker` constructor will not be called.

> What can i do to call the constructor of all the 10 objects of class
>   checker?

Create new instances of `checker` in a loop (or in some other way) and add them to your array.

Answer (score 0):

`obj=new checker[10]` just sets `obj` to an array of `checker` objects. It does not fill the array with new `checker`s. To do that, you will need to do something like this:

```
obj=new checker[10];
for (int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
 obj[i] = new checker();
}
```

To answer your question more generally, to call the constructor, you must invoke the `new` keyword explicitly.

Comment: It might be worth amending your answer to make it clear that the array isn't really an array of `checker` objects - it's an array of *references*.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating ten empty boxes(null references) to hold references of ten objects. For calling constructor for ten objects, you have to loop through these ten empty boxes and store reference of a new object in each box. i.e.

```
Checker[] chkArray = new Checker[10];
for (int i = 0; i < checkers.length; i++) {
    chkArray[i] = new Checker();
}
```